# Is the "quantum world" dialogue between Oppenheimer and Einstein based on a real quote?

Tags: dialogue, realism, oppenheimer

Did Einstein ever say, "And here we are, lost in your quantum world of probabilities, but needing certainty," to Oppenheimer and if so, where could such a quote be found?

Comment: I doubt it ... sounds quite script-like.  Unless such a quote appeared in a letter between them, or was repeated by one of them to the press - which seems unlikely - I don't think such a conversation would be recorded.

Comment: It's a good line, showcasing Einstein's scepticism, but it's a *very* private dialogue in the movie.

Answer (score 20):

This [article in Vanity Fair](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2023/07/oppenheimer-einstein-movie-real-life) includes a quote from Nolan (to the New York Times) that the entire scene is a fiction

> The scene, Nolan admits, is an invention. In reality, Oppenheimer did fear causing a chain reaction—but he sought counsel from Arthur Compton, a Nobel Prize winner who directed the Manhattan Project’s University of Chicago outpost, instead of the man behind the theory of relativity. “I shifted that to Einstein,” Nolan told The New York Times, because “Einstein is the personality people know in the audience.”

Comment: It's also consistent with Einstein's famous "God does not play dice" quote. So it seems like something he *could* have said if they had that discussion.

Comment: I think it's a fair decision, Compton is unknown to non-physicists.